# Create a graph to display observed and fitted values

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, model-fitting

I am trying to plot the observed and fitted values from a data set and its linear regression against a common time period variable using `ggplot`.

My data frame is called `balances`.

```
gdp.model <- lm(depvar ~ 
              indepvar1 + 
              indepvar2 + 
              indepvar3, 
            data = balances)

gdp.fitted <- ggplot(data = balances,
                 mapping = aes(x = observation.num, y = depvar)) +
                 geom_line() + 
                 geom_line(data = gdp.model,
                           mapping = aes(y = fitted.values))
```

My intention was to plot the fitted values and observed values on a common axis and the time period variable - `observation.num` - from balances on the other axis. However, because there is no time period variable in the `gdp.model` object, I keep getting an error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'observation.num' not
>   found

Is there any simple way to get around the issue of the fitted values not having a common time variable?

Comment: Look up `fortify()` function in `library(ggplot2)`

Comment: And `gdp.model` isn't a data frame, it's a `lm` object. Listen to Vlo and `fortify` your data.

Comment: ... or straight up the `broom` package and its `augment` function, as `fortify` doesn't seem to be here for long.